# Wrong answer Test Case Skipped Google kick start Round E 2020 Longest Arithmetic

Tags: python

hi guys i am trying to solve this problem but i am getting wrong answer error test case skipped on submit but on test cases output is fine. here is my code.
program is working for test cases i mention bellow but its still not submitting i don't understand why test cases are skipping.
please let me know where is the problem

```
for x in range( int ( input() ) ):
    length = int(input())
    num = list(map(int,input().split()))
    d = num[1]-num[0]
    temp = d
    count = 2
    max_len =0
    for i in range(1,length - 1):
        d = num[i+1] - num[i]
        if d == temp:
            temp = d
            count+=1
            max_len = max(max_len,count)
        else:
            temp = d    
            max_len = max(max_len,count)
            count = 2
    print("Case #" + str(x+1) + ": " + str(max_len))
```

sample test cases :

```
13
3
5 5 5
8
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 8
8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
7
10 7 4 6 8 10 11
4
9 7 5 3
9
5 5 4 5 5 5 4 5 6
10
5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
5
1 2 3 4 5
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
3
4 6 8
9
6 9 11 12 13 14 1 2 3
6
7 8 9 10 1 2
8
5 3 1 0 2 3 4 5
```

and output for these test cases

Case #1: 3

Case #2: 4

Case #3: 8

Case #4: 4

Case #5: 4

Case #6: 3

Case #7: 6

Case #8: 5

Case #9: 10

Case #10: 3

Case #11: 4

Case #12: 4

Case #13: 4

Comment: Please add the question as well

Comment: sorry about that i just re edited question.